# Removing percentage signs with R

Tags: r

I am learning R and have a tutorial that wants me to remove the percent sign.  The code they want me to use is:

```
 chocolateData$Cocoa_Percent <- sapply(chocolateData$Cocoa_Percent, function(x) gsub("%", "", x))
```

My question pertains to what I may be typing wrong, or if there is a different way to do this with R?

Comment: your code is correct and works for me. can you give a simple example that is not working for you? > cd <- NULL > cd$c <- c('test1%', 'test2%') > cd <- as.data.frame(cd) > cd$c [1] test1% test2% > cd$c <- sapply(cd$c, function(x) gsub("%","",x)) > cd$c [1] "test1" "test2"

Comment: If you just want to remove the percent sign for a single column use `gsub("%", "", chocolateData$Cocoa_Percent)`

Comment: tried it, not working on my system.

Comment: chocolateData$Cocoa.Percent = as.numeric(gsub("[\\%,]", "", chocolateData$Cocoa.Percent))

Answer (score 3):

The following code worked, thanks for the assistance.

`chocolateData$Cocoa.Percent = as.numeric(gsub("[\\%,]", "", chocolateData$Cocoa.Percent))`